# Can I use node red worldmap node without internet connection

Tags: raspberry-pi, node-red, world-map

I need to use node red worlmap node without using internet. I installed worldmap using internet and I need to use node with out active internet connection

I tried it, sometimes works. Sometimes not. When I connect to the internet map shows, but couple of hours after disconnecting internet map is not visible. Only white screen.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you have to host your own map tile server and configure it to use those tiles.

See the section of the README that talks about "Using local map server"

Running a map tile server is non trivial and can require a LOT of storage, unless you only want titles for a small area of the world.

The intermittent nature you are seeing is probably the browser cache timing out.